# Creating global functions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the legacy system with some JS code, and currently, I am working on refactoring and extracting logic to typescript files. (My further goal is to rewrite it to Angular).

I have some javascript code that uses global function `logout()` in it, and I wanted to move it into typescript, the one problem is that browser is unable to recognize this function as global...

I have tried following

```js
declare global {
    function logout(): void;
}

function logout() {
// some logic
}
```

But after invoking it globally I have an exception: 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: logout is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

Am I trying to do this properly or is there another way of creating global functions that can be accessible from js?

Comment: does it need global declaration?

Comment: Yes, I have some js code that uses this function, and right now I am unable to refactor that part of the system. I have to do it incrementally. Afterwards, it will be removed, but I have to prepare POC right now...

Comment: did you tried an iife for creating global?

Comment: `declare function logout(): void;` try removing global
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-functions